# read http header info in ASIHttpRequest asynchronous

Tags: iphone

One of my project is to download several large size files using ASIHTTPRequest in asynchronous mode.
I hope to read the http returned header info to get the size of files.
I know [request respsonseHeaders] (requestFinished: delegate method ) can do that.
I tested and found that requestFinished: is only triggered when it completed the download of a whole single file.
But I hope to access the function [request respsonseHeaders]  before ASIHTTPRequest starting to download files (just when ASIHTTPRequest got the returned header info).

I can not find the triggered event for this.

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look at the `-handleBytesAvailable` method. It's a callback method that reads data that streams in. You might also look at the `-readResponseHeaders` method, where the header is processed.

Answer (score 4):

A new delegate method was recently added to ASIHTTPRequest for this purpose:

```
- (void)requestReceivedResponseHeaders:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[request responseHeaders]);
}
```

You can have the request call a different method on your delegate by setting didReceiveResponseHeadersSelector.